# is it Ok to use swing timer outside swing?

Tags: java, timer

As title says, is it acceptable to use swing timer in not-swing application?

Or would I be better off writing my own using a separate thread?

I'm unaware of what disadvantages swing timer might have, but I tend to use things that are already there.

Comment: What's wrong with java.util.Timer ?

Comment: OK in what sense? Are you concerned by a license? By whether it will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than
>   general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all
>   share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task
>   automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. **However, you
>   might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the
>   GUI** from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

I should recommend using the `util.Timer`.

Answer (score 2):

No, use Swing timer only when your are working on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
Other than that you can use `java.util.Timer`.

Also, Swing timer are slower than util timer as they are designed to work on GUI.